# how to split any url and get only source?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split `https://abcnews.go.com/` this type of URL.

Want to get **abcnews**

I used:

```
.split('//')[1]
.split('www.')[1]
.split('.com')[0]
.split('.org')[0]
.split('.edu')[0]
.split('.info')[0]
```

I get error can not split.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: `s.match(/:\/\/([^.\/]+)/)[1]`

Comment: if the url has www.something.com then I get only www

Comment: Please update the question with all your requirements. Try `(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)([^.\/]+)/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/r1YcFe/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks safe:

```
(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)([^.\/]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/r1YcFe/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.\/]+                  any character except: '.', '\/' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const url = "https://abcnews.go.com/"
const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)([^.\/]+)/
const match = url.match(regex)
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you accept Regex's response?

```js
const url='https://abcnews.go.com/';
let subdomain = url.match(/(\w*)\./)[1];

console.log(subdomain)
// subdomain = "abcnews"
```

With that, you get the word before the first dot.

---

I think you get an error after:
`.split('//')[1].split('www.')[1]`
Because you have no "www", then the length of the array is 1 (array[0] only).

```js
const rgx=/(?:www\.)?(\w*)\./;
const abc='https://abcnews.go.com/';
const www='https://www.google.com/';

console.log(abc.match(rgx)[1]);
// "abcnews"

console.log(www.match(rgx)[1]);
// "google"
```